# jQuery dialog, nothing happen

Tags: jquery, dialog

```
$(function() {
    $( "#Dialog1" ).dialog({
        resizable: false
    }); 

    if($( "#Dialog1" ).dialog( "isOpen" )){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#Dialog1" ).dialog( "option", "hide", {
                effect: "explode", 
                duration: 1000
            } ) 
        }, 5000)}   
    });
});
```

It needs to destroy the dialog after 5 seconds but nothing happened.

Comment: `dialog("option", "hide", ...)` does not hide the dialog. Use `close` or `destroy` instead. See the difference in [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Try this $(this).dialog('close'); if not your solution explain what error you getting in console

Comment: It closes the dialog, but the setTimeOut not work.

Comment: What error you getting

Comment: Nothing. Console: A getUserData() vagy setUserData() használata elavult. Használja helyette WeakMap-et vagy az element.dataset-et. requestNotifier.js:63
A getPreventDefault() használata elavult. Használja helyette a defaultPrevented-et.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You have an extra `}` after `setTimeout`
2. You have an extra `)` after the closing `}` of the if statement
3. When calling a method you do not need `"option"`
4. To close the dialog use `close` or `destroy` methods

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/4Ea5e/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#Dialog1" ).dialog({
        resizable: false
    }); 

    if( $( "#Dialog1" ).dialog( "isOpen" ) ){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#Dialog1" ).dialog( "close" ); 
        }, 5000);   
    }
});
```